# Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. But it's already in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-hooks, react-data-grid

I'm following the tutorial here: http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/column-sorting and trying to implement react-data-grid as it provides me the functionality of doing sorting, tree kind of view for a particular cell etc. But I'm getting an error like below:

Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";
import "./styles.css";

const defaultColumnProperties = {
    resizable: true,
    sortable: true,
    width: 300
};

const columns = [
    { key: "key1", name: "key1", sortDescendingFirst: true },
    { key: "key2", name: "key2" },
    { key: "key3", name: "key3" },
    { key: "key4", name: "key4" },
    { key: "key5", name: "key5" }
].map(c => ({ ...c, ...defaultColumnProperties }));

const sortRows = (initialRows, sortColumn, sortDirection) => rows => {
    const comparer = (a, b) => {
        if (sortDirection === "ASC") {
            return a[sortColumn] > b[sortColumn] ? 1 : -1;
        } else if (sortDirection === "DESC") {
            return a[sortColumn] < b[sortColumn] ? 1 : -1;
        }
    };
    return sortDirection === "NONE" ? initialRows : [...rows].sort(comparer);
};

class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { data: [] };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://localhost:8080";
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                mode: "cors",
                method: "GET"
            });
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response);
            }
            const res = await response.json();

            this.setState({ data: res });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    someStateFunction = data => {
        return useState(data);
    };

    render() {
        const [rows, setRows] = this.someStateFunction(
            this.state.data
        );
        return (
            <ReactDataGrid
                columns={columns}
                rowGetter={i => rows[i]}
                rowsCount={rows.length}
                minHeight={5000}
                onColumnResize={(idx, width) =>
                    console.log(`Column ${idx} has been resized to ${width}`)
                }
                onGridSort={(sortColumn, sortDirection) =>
                    setRows(
                        sortRows(
                            this.state.data,
                            sortColumn,
                            sortDirection
                        )
                    )
                }
            />
        );
    }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
```

How do i resolve it?
`useState()` is used inside a function only? Am i doing it in a wrong way?

package.json looks like below:

```
{
  "name": "dc-react-test-2",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.32.4",
    "react-data-grid": "5.0.1",
    "immutable": "3.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Please help. I am a very newbie to react.

Answer (score 1):

`Example` is not a function component in your example, it's a class component. A function component is just a regular javascript function. [Here is an article about the difference.](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-functional-components/)

Here you are mixing class component states and function component states (`useState`). You have to choose. Either you stick with the class component, and you have to add some state to `this.state` to keep track of sortings, etc., or you go full functional and you do your fetch [in a `useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: Can you guide me what changes needs to be done in my code, to make use of functional component or class component? Here my requirement is to make use of async/await to do rest api call and also make use of useState() as shown in my code.